# how to use if else condition for deleting data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am using mysql workbench. I am updating the data @ 8AM and 2PM every night it should delete the 8AM data i wrote the query for it and it's running successfully but my problem is sometimes the server is down 2PM so the data couldn't update on 2PM so if it happened i need to have the 8AM data so the mysql should check whether the Data is updated on 2PM if it's updated it should delete the 8AM data if not it should not delete the 8AM data
`if time=2PM then delete from database where time=8AM`
how can i write the query for it please help me with this.

Thank you,
Regards,
Jen

Comment: Removed the incompatible tags

Comment: Can you include your table's data structure (output of `desc tablename`) and the query you have written?

Comment: Your English is illegible, can you type into google translate in your native language and edit that into your question.

Comment: What specific programming language are you using? Provide us more information so that we can help you.

You can also put your code here for reference.

Comment: Do you want to delete all 8AM data or is there any other conditions to be applied ? according to your `IF` info it will delete all 8AM data.

Comment: I am using sql . everyday night the 8AM data will get deleted and i want to check whether i have the 2PM update before deleting the 8AM

Answer (score 0):

I think that the simplest approach would be something like this (pseudo-code):

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) <rest of query counting the updates at 2PM) > 0 THEN
    DELETE <data from 8AM>
END IF ;
```

Though this can also be implemented in a single query, what runs in the background would be more or less the same BUT this code would be much easy to **READ and UNDERSTAND** (i.e. your eyes on future maintenance activities).